# Detecting writes to memory segment of a static linked library coming NOT from this library

Tags: memory-management, static-libraries, memory-corruption

I am facing a problem here where code that uses several static linked libraries seems to corrupt memory belonging to a Microsoft library. I think it is quite unlikely that the MS library itself has such a bug. From my investigation it is also very unlikely that the corruption is caused by a call to the library. So my current idea is that in the main application or one of the libraries it uses there is a call to a memcpy or something similar that causes a corruption of data belonging to the MS library. Normally I would use data breakpoints to trace down such an error but unfortunately in this case this is not suitable. The crash only occurs once every 10 or so hours but memory belonging to the MS library is changed once every 2ms or even in shorter time periods by valid calls to that library.

So I was wondering if it is possible to detect if a library or the main executable is writing to a memory segment that belongs to the MS library, because I think that this is most likely the cause of my current problem.